# Unable to fetch an email link out of some script tag from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to scrape an email address from a webpage but I am not being able to. The email address is sit within a `script` tag and I can't smash that barrier to fetch the content. Any help to get that will be much appreciated.

[Webpage link](http://www.the-ida.com/index.php?option=com_community&view=profile&userid=31033393)

I've tried so far with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "replace_with_link_above"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
for items in soup.select(".profile-right-info"):
    email = items.select_one("dd a[href^='mailto:']")['href']
    print(email)
```

Upon execution I get the below error:

```
    email = items.select_one("dd a[href^='mailto:']")['href']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Btw, the email link is at the second row under the title `profile details` in that webpage.

Comment: The address is protected, so be sure you get if with something like selemium with javascript enabled, i assume you did this with urllib / requests. The error mesns that ```items.select_one("dd a[href^='mailto:']")``` is None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the Network tab of the Chrome dev tools:

[image]

There is a block of code:

```
 <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
 <!--
 var prefix = 'm&#97;&#105;lt&#111;:';
 var suffix = '';
 var attribs = '';
 var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
 var addy99716 = "R&#111;bz" + '&#64;';
 addy99716 = addy99716 + '&#97;ll&#105;nth&#101;p&#111;l&#105;sh' + '&#46;' + 'c&#111;m';
 document.write( '<a ' + path + '"' + prefix + addy99716 + suffix + '"' + attribs + '>' );
 document.write( addy99716 );
 document.write( '<\/a>' );
 //-->
 </script>
```

which evaluates to `<a>` tag with `href` attribute equal to:

```
m&#97;&#105;lt&#111;:R&#111;bz&#64;&#97;ll&#105;nth&#101;p&#111;l&#105;sh&#46;c&#111;m
```

which will be `mailto:Robz@allinthepolish.com` if you decode the html entities, you could check it here: https://mothereff.in/html-entities

So, one option would be using something like Selenium as [cgte proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282121/unable-to-fetch-an-email-link-out-of-some-script-tag-from-a-webpage#comment87580941_50282121).

The other option is to get the contents of the `<dd>` tag, parse the js code and then either run it with `node` executable (which could be dangerous if you will not run it in a sandbox) or evaluate manually. The option with Selenium seems a lot more simple.